How to set MAUI status bar color using styles?
Simply using CommunityToolkit.Maui's StatusBarColor and StatusBarStyle in the Page style has no effect.
Answering my own question here, based on a video by Oludayu Alli.

Wild question, isn't this like implemented already in the community toolkit?

@H.A.H. It is, for one page at a time. When you try to put it in a Style to cover all pages, it doesn't work because the properties are not attached properties. Anyway, FreakyAli has a good suggestion.

Who told you its for one page at a time?

@H.A.H. Happy to be corrected ...

using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Behaviors;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core;

namespace MyApp.Custom
{
    class CustomStatusBarBehavior : Behavior<Page>
    // Allows control of status bar color and style, using CommunityToolkit.Maui's StatusBarColor and StatusBarStyle to define ct:CustomStatusBarColor and ct:CustomStatusBarStyle
    // Uses attached properties
    //
    // Usage:
    // 1. Place this file in a new folder called Custom, say.
    // 2. In Styles.xaml, add the following namespaces:
    //        xmlns:mct="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"       
    //        xmlns:ct="clr-namespace:MyApp.Custom"
    //    and add the following to the <Page> style:
    //        <Setter Property="ct:CustomStatusBarBehavior.StatusBarColor" Value="RoyalBlue" />
    //        <Setter Property="ct:CustomStatusBarBehavior.StatusBarStyle" Value="LightContent" /> (or DarkContent)
    {
        private static Color StatusColor = Color.FromRgb ( red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 );
        private static StatusBarStyle StatusStyle = StatusBarStyle.Default;
        public static readonly BindableProperty StatusBarColorProperty =
                                    BindableProperty.CreateAttached ( propertyName: "StatusBarColor",
                                                                 typeof (Color),
                                                                 typeof (CustomStatusBarBehavior),
                                                                 Color.FromRgb ( red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0 ),
                                                                 propertyChanged: OnStatusBarColorChanged );

        public static readonly BindableProperty StatusBarStyleProperty =
                                    BindableProperty.CreateAttached ( propertyName: "StatusBarStyle",
                                                                 typeof (StatusBarStyle),
                                                                 typeof (CustomStatusBarBehavior),
                                                                 StatusBarStyle.Default,
                                                                 propertyChanged: OnStatusBarStyleChanged );

        public static Color GetStatusBarColor ( BindableObject view )
        {
            return (Color)view.GetValue ( StatusBarColorProperty );
        }

        public static void SetStatusBarColor ( BindableObject view, Color value )
        {
            view.SetValue ( StatusBarColorProperty, value );
        }

        public static StatusBarStyle GetStatusBarStyle ( BindableObject view )
        {
            return (StatusBarStyle)view.GetValue ( StatusBarStyleProperty );
        }

        public static void SetStatusBarStyle ( BindableObject view, StatusBarStyle value )
        {
            view.SetValue ( StatusBarStyleProperty, value );
        }

        private static void OnStatusBarColorChanged ( BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue )
        {
            Page page = view as Page;

            if ( page != null )
            {
                if ( (Color)newValue != (Color)oldValue )
                {
                    StatusColor = (Color)newValue;
                    AddBehavior ( page );
                }
            }
        }

        private static void OnStatusBarStyleChanged ( BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue )
        {
            Page page = view as Page;

            if ( page != null )
            {
                if ( (StatusBarStyle)newValue != (StatusBarStyle)oldValue )
                {
                    StatusStyle = (StatusBarStyle)newValue;
                    AddBehavior ( page );
                }
            }
        }

        private static void AddBehavior ( Page page )
        {
            page.Behaviors.Add ( item: new StatusBarBehavior
            {
                StatusBarColor = StatusColor,
                StatusBarStyle = StatusStyle
            });
        }
    }
}


Why do so much work when you can just set it in a BasePage with 2 properties?

Thanks for the suggestion, @FreakyAli. Your posts have helped me innumerable times and I really want to thank you for that.

Hey no worries if you ever feel stuck with something feel free to reach out!
